# How to retrieve a custom configuration file in DolphinDB? Can I import a script file into another script file?

Tags: dolphindb

I need to modify some configuration parameters for my script. I'd like to keep these parameters in an independent file while saving the rest of the code in another. Any way I can do that in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

Use the statement `#include` to import user script.
In this example, the script is saved as `config.dos`.

```
a=100
```

Then open a new script file, where you can use include to import `config.dos`.

```
#include "/yourPath/config.dos"
```

Note: Use the GUI path when the code is running in GUI. Use the server path when running in the script `startup.dos`.